# Unable to cast COM object of type 'RDPCOMAPILib.RDPSessionClass' to interface type 'RDPCOMAPILib.IRDPSRAPISharingSession2'

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, windows-10, rdp

Full Error:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'RDPCOMAPILib.RDPSessionClass' to interface 
type 'RDPCOMAPILib.IRDPSRAPISharingSession2'. This operation failed because 
the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 
'{FEE4EE57-E3E8-4205-8FB0-8FD1D0675C21}' failed due to the following error: No 
such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

This is part of a remote destop viewing application very similar to this:

http://daron.yondem.com/software/post/d8bbab27-169d-43d4-aea7-494845891789

Error fires on this line

```
Dim x As New RDPSession
AddHandler x.OnAttendeeConnected, AddressOf Incoming
x.Open()
```

App coded in Windows 10 and works fine on it, error is happening on Windows 7 (although I think Vista onwards is supported?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, breaking change in Win10, XxxSession2 is now the default interface and, as the error message says, not available on Win7.  Copying c:\windows\system32\rdpencom.dll off the Win7 machine and creating the interop library with Tlbimp.exe is best.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Is there anywhere I can learn how to do this?